# Wordpress Rhythm Theme social icons style change for header

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is a styling question for anyone who uses the popular Rhythm Theme for Wordpress. I would like to use the footer style of social icons in the header, but no matter how I fiddle with the settings I can't make it so. Here's what I want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to have in mind you will have to change the header background color to have the same color behavior of the footer icons on top.

Second I don't think the person who designed the theme was planning to do what you have in mind, so probably you will have to create a child theme and change some css rules creating your own files.